# My site doesn't look the same after uploading to host

Tags: html, css, styles, hosting

After I uploaded my site to the host the style has changed.  Notice the header, when I mocked it up the two icons were lined up with the phone number (see below).  I'm going crazy over here!

[www.kilgorerodriguez.com](http://www.kilgorerodriguez.com)

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you hardcode the link to your CSS files?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, sorry.  It's jus the index.html that's not right.  I'll look into hardcoding (?) the css file. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your p tag which holds your phone number to the below it will work.

```
<p style="float:left;"><span style="color: #b1cc29;"> 770.693.4358</span></p>
```

Comment: Of course! Thanks @Mista Josh I figured it was something simple like that.  What was so confusing was that when I was previewing the site in the same browser it looked fine.